# regroup the close points

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geometry, mapinfo

I have a list of 10 000 points, and I wish consolidate 15 points each in a block in the vicinity.
I use arcgis, or mapinfo qgis, I just need the method.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you click 'edit' and explain more about what you want to do here? What do you want to produce - a polygon? Are there a large number of points which need to be grouped into sets of 15 each?

Comment: What software are you using, or wanting to use, to try and do this?  Without focussing on a particular software you are effectively asking multiple questions.  From the [Tour] you will see that there should be only one question per question.

Comment: thanks for your answer

To be clear, I have a group of 10,000 stores throughout the country, for which I have to make a visit planning, and for that I have a block of 15 together.
I utliser mapinfo, and arcgis qgis, I just need a method

Comment: Could you click 'edit' and update your original question with those details? Also, you'll need to explain what criteria you want to use to group 15 stores together - what if there are 40 in close proximity, how would you decide which set of 15 each belongs to? What if one store is a long way off by itself, should it still be forced to belong to a set of 15?

Comment: If you add a picture to your question it may make what you are trying to describe easier to understand.

Comment: something like that http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000051000000